# html_entity_decode to plain text or not utf (elipsis to ... , etc)

Tags: php, html-entities

Trying to figure out this decoding.  I want to wind up with the most generic text possible. Elipsis to '...' Fancy quotes to single or double quotes, regular old '-' not the emdash.  Is there another way other than str_replace with a table of fancy vs. regular strings?

```
$str = 'Hey,&#8230;I came back&#8230;.ummm,&#8230;OK,&#8230;cool';

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES) ;
// Hey,&#8230;I came back&#8230;.ummm,&#8230;OK,&#8230;cool

echo html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15')  ;
// Hey,&#8230;I came back&#8230;.ummm,&#8230;OK,&#8230;cool

echo html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')  ;
//this works, but changes to the elipse character 
// Hey,…I came back….ummm,…OK,…cool

echo str_replace("&#8230;", "...", $str)  ;
//Hey,...I came back....ummm,...OK,...cool
//desired result
```

Comment: See the [`strtr()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your specs but I have the impression you want something like this:

```
$str = 'Hey,&#8230;I came back&#8230;.ummm,&#8230;OK,&#8230;cool';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

This basically makes any Unicode character fit into 7-bit ASCII. Unexpected results may arise.

**Update:** Examples of unexpected results:

```
$str = '&Aacute;lvaro Espa&ntilde;a €&pound;&yen;&cent;&copy;&reg;';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
# 'Alvaro Espa~na EURlbyenc(c)(R)

$str = 'Test: &#xb89;&#xba4;&#xbbe;&#xbb0;&#xba3;';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
# Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

$str = 'Test: &#xb89;&#xba4;&#xbbe;&#xbb0;&#xba3; End Test';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
# Test:  End Test
```

You should note that HTML entities like `&#8230;` are just a trick to allow browsers to display characters that do not belong to the document encoding. They have nothing to do with databases! If you're getting them into your DB it's probably because your app is not using UTF-8 (UTF-8 allows to represent *any* character) but users are typing those characters anyway and the browser makes its best to fit them into the document. The easiest fix it to just switch to UTF-8, as explained in [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

> Fb doesnt like these &# characters and I would assume doesnt like the elipsis characters either

HTML entities are, well, HTML, not plain text. If Facebook expects plain text, HTML entities will displayed as-is rather than being decoded. As about «…», I really doubt that Facebook (which is using UTF-8) treats them exceptionally. You're probably sending them in the wrong encoding.

Comment: This is looking good with a couple test cases. I am getting the string from a user form, put into wp db (and i assume this is the point it's being encoded to the &#8230; ) and I am sending the string to facebook, via fb graph. Fb doesnt like these &# characters and I would assume doesnt like the elipsis characters either.  Which is why i'm wanting to translate it to ascii, the most basic as possible.  Can you give examples of the unexpected results you have run accross?